# How do I sketch the step response given the poles and zeroes?

Tags: matlab, control-theory

[like here for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xdua.png)
. I sort of understand the general concept, but I've been trying to research but haven't found any examples, I'd greatly appreciate if someone can help me understand the concept.

Comment: A late response, but I think this document is a good summary. Realize that the location of the poles on the real/imaginary plane correspond to the natural frequency and damping ratio (see root locus on wikipedia). http://web.mit.edu/2.737/www/extra_files/unused%20files/trans.pdf